# using limits to query sqlite table in python

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I am trying to return multiple rows using a basic sqlite table using python. I modified the code slightly from the tutorials:

```
 import sqlite3
 conn = sqlite3.connect('SQL_test_3.db') #this creates a seperate file
 c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('drop table if exists stocks')
c.execute('''create table stocks
(date text, trans text, symbol text,
 qty real, price real)''')

data = [('2006-03-28', 'BUY', 'IBM', 1000, 45.00),
      ('2006-04-05', 'BUY', 'MSFT', 1000, 72.00),
      ('2006-04-06', 'SELL', 'IBM', 500, 53.00),
      ('0000-00-00', 'Test', 'Test', 100, 100)
     ]

 for t in data:
     c.execute('insert into stocks values (?,?,?,?,?)', t)

conn.commit()

price = 72
t = (price,)

c.execute('select * from stocks where price=? limit 2', t)
print c.fetchall()
```

I would like it to return:

```
[(u'2006-04-05', u'BUY', u'MSFT', 1000.0, 72.0)]
[(u'2006-04-06', u'SELL', u'IBM', 500.0, 53.0)]
```

I thought about using the command:

```
c.execute('select * from stocks where price=? limit 2', t)
```

But it only returns the first row. I tried using offsets but that doesn't seem to work. Does anyone know how to solve this? If anyone could help that would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn Yes only one row is returned. I would like multiple rows returned - based on where price is located.

Answer (score 0):

Only 1 row is returned when querying without `LIMIT` as well. This is not a `LIMIT` problem.

The issue is the `WHERE` part of your query: `price = 72` only matches 1 row.

Comment: Ok. What I want is to return the row where the price is 72 but I also want the row after that. If LIMIT is not the answer, what is?

Comment: @dave In SQL tables, row order is not defined. Please edit your question to specify what exactly you mean with "after that".

Comment: @CL. What I mean by "after that" is that I want is to identify a row that contains the price - Return its row then then return the next row in the table. Essentially I want to find a range of rows from a starting position. In this case I want the starting position to be price. So when I find price at a certain value, return its row and the next adjacent rows. I hope I'm making sense. Sorry if I'm not.

Comment: **There is no "next row in the table"**. Order is not guaranteed, and won't remain constant. You have to explicitly `SORT` your query. If you want items cheaper than `72`, `SORT BY price`, `WHERE price <= 72`, then `LIMIT` if need be.